# Sending emails via AWS Lambda with an SPF record

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, aws-lambda, spf

I have a [Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) that occasionally needs to send emails via `SMTP`.

Some recipients are consistently blocking emails sent from my Lambda code, due to lack of an `SPF record` on my domain.

How can I add an `SPF record` to my domain when using `Lambda`, if I can't tell in advance which server the email will be sent from?

Comment: The way your question is written, it sounds as if you are doing direct-to-MX from Lambda which would be completely impractical.  There should be an intermediate server -- a smarthost -- somewhere in yout configurarion, but you have not mentioned one... so we need to figure out whether you have one.  Can you show the code that sends the email -- particularly the SMTP settings?

Comment: I'm not using any intermediate server, I'm using the nodemailer package to send emails from time to time from my lambda function, why would you say this would be impractical? I'm currently exploring Lambda as a way to build something without any perm. server, an intermediate server for email sending would fail this ambition...

Comment: Not using an intermediate **SMTP server** (or a mail delivery service provider like SES or Mandrill or SendGrid or similar) is a thoroughly and completely the flawed strategy, if indeed that is what you are trying to do.  Email must be marshalled at a fixed base, somewhere, for applying appropriate message timing and delivery policies, handling retries and slow or unreachable mail services, and for a number of other reasons.  Sending email direct-to-target-MX from the point of origination, as you seem to be attempting, is fraught with unspeakable peril... here be dragons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an SPF record with AWS Lambda. Here is how you can add an SPF record: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html